# regular expression false delimiter in wordpress

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I am newbie to regular expression and I have this simple doubt.

I have found this code in wordpress

```
$self = preg_replace('|^.*/wp-admin/|i', '', $self);
```

according to the [doc on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) `|` is not permissible as delimiter..

Can someone explain the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried it?

From your [link](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

> When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is enclosed by delimiters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.

So `|` is a perfectly valid delimiter. When you read the comments on that page, they suggest to not use meta characters (like `|`) as delimiters, when they should be used inside the regex.

Since there is no alternation in your example `$self = preg_replace('|^.*/wp-admin/|i', '', $self);` there is no problem and it is working as expected.

When you have an alternation in the regex (e.g. `preg_match("|(F|f)oo|", "Foobar")`) you will get a warning "Unknown modifier 'f'", because the interpreter thinks the regex does end at the first alternation.

**Conclusion: It's allowed, but not recommended to use regex meta-characters like `|`, `^`, `+`, ... as regex delimiters.**