# The Different Delimiters of Regex

Tags: regex, delimiter

When I look up regular expressions for various purposes, I see people using delimiters like `/`, `#`, `!`, and `~`. Do these do anything different, or do they have the same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't do anything different, they delimit the regular expression (in languages where it is needed).

The difference is: the behaviour of that character inside the regex does change. The regex delimiter becomes an additional special character and needs to be escaped (==> choose a delimiter that you don't need within the regex!).

Side note: In php you can even use a regex special character like `+` or `|` as regex delimiter, but this works only when you don't need that character inside the regex (NOT recommended). [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10456508/626273)

Answer (score 1):

In some languages you can choose the delimiters, in others you can't.

You must escape that delimiter every time it appears in the regular expression. Choosing a delimiter that does not occur in the expression reduces the need for escaping, making the expression easier to read.

The following two regular expressions are identical, except that the first uses `/` as a delimiter, whereas the second uses `#`:

```
/http:\/\/example\.com\/.*\/foo\//
#http://example\.com/.*/foo/#
```